# iPhone SDK: Nearby Locations Feature

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I have an iphone app which displays a list of businesses and their location on a Google Map using the MKMapView. As a new feature, I am trying to add a "Nearby" feature, whereby it gets the users current location and displays several map annotations on a google map within the vicinity of say 10KM. Currently, the businesses location is stored as an address string in a mysql database, this is then retrieved and geocoded to display it on a google map.

How do I go about doing this? If there is any tutorials around, please point me to one. (I haven't had any luck with finding one).
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I got it partially working - it's only displaying businesses within a 20KM radius which is great, the problem i'm having is that when they open this Nearby Businesses View, it takes quite some time for it to go through each business and check the distance between the user and each individual business. Is there any way to speed this up? Here is my code:, both these methods are called from the viewDidLoad method.

```
-(void)getMapData
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    NSInteger *bizMax = [[numOfBiz objectAtIndex:0]intValue];

    int x = 0;
    while(x < bizMax)
    {

        NSURL *mapURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"getBizMap-xml.php?biz_id=%@",[bizIDS objectAtIndex:x]]];
        NSMutableArray *mapArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mapURL];
        self.mapLocation = mapArray;
        self.mapStringLocation = [mapArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Location: %@",mapStringLocation);
        [mapArray release];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D trueLocation = [self getLocationFromAddressString:mapStringLocation];
        AddressAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:trueLocation];

        CLLocation *bizLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:trueLocation.latitude longitude:trueLocation.longitude];

        CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:nearbyMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:nearbyMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        //double distance = [userLocation getDistanceFrom: bizLoc] / 1000;

        double kilometers = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:bizLoc] / 1000;

        NSLog(@"Distance from %@ to current location is %g",mapStringLocation,kilometers);

        if(kilometers < maxDistance)
        {    
            [self.nearbyMapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
            [addAnnotation release];   
        }

        x++;
    }

    [pool release];        
}

-(void)getNumOfBusinesses
{    
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    NSString *numOfBizJSON = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"numOfBiz.php"]]];

    NSString *bizIDSJSON = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"allBizIDSJSON.php"]]];

    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    numOfBiz = [[parser objectWithString:numOfBizJSON error:nil]copy];
    bizIDS = [[parser objectWithString:bizIDSJSON error:nil]copy];
    NSLog(@"biz id 1 = %@",[bizIDS objectAtIndex:0]);
    [parser release];
    [numOfBizJSON release];
    [bizIDSJSON release];

    [pool release];   
}
```

Comment: Any chance the source data could embed the GPS location as well as their address? Or better yet the webservice you're calling to offer a summary which includes all the businesses in one hit. If you've got too many to reasonably fit into one response then you've got too many to loop through individually too.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't that hard. You can fetch all your data, calculate the distance between you and the location. The next step would be comparing the distance with the maxDistance(the search radius). If the distance < maxDistance, add you can display that location.

I think this could be achieved with very little cocoa knowledge...

If you need something more specific, start coding and I'll help you with that.